# Run web project on Server Tomcat 7 with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I have big web application that uses GWT. When it starts a dialog window is openning on client side for logging. LogDialog consists of two textfields (password and name). Why when I use option Run on Server from Eclipse  I can see only loading picture(it appears from beginnig). But then the LogDialog and main menu dont appear. As I know there is one jscript that Browser have to load to show Logdialog. I tried to view web app from GooGle Chrome and I discovered that it doesnt load Cashier.js (jscript file) and shows to me loading picture. What am I doing wrong? How can I catch the error?
As I know GWT compiler generate the client side Javascript code. The web app uses database for storing logname and pass.

Comment: I have tried it again and I got the message

Comment: INFO: springGwtRemoteServiceServletBack: ERROR: The serialization policy file '/Cashier/66ECCC3D8F4C93A448BAE7B38819221D.gwt.rpc' was not found; did you forget to include it in this deployment?

Comment: How to include rpc file on running